# why printf inside in the for loop can anybody explain me?

Tags: c

I tried this code on id but can't understand

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=1;
    int j=1;

    for(;j;printf("%d%d\t",i,j))
        j=i++<=5;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this code was written to make people to not understand.

Comment: you should look and see what the return value of `printf` is

Comment: @bruceg The return value of `printf()` is ignored.

Comment: The only benefit of such a beast is that you don't need to enclose the body of the loop in braces.

Comment: Don't waste time on code like this.

Answer (score 2):

As Eugene Sh. says, this source is written to be no understandable, at least for beginners.

Let's unroll the problematic lines!

The `for` loop can be rewritten as a `while` loop, with initial statement, loop condition and loop statement separated. The `for` loop controls just one statement and has therefore no encloseding curly braces.

```
for(; j; printf("%d%d\t", i, j))
    /* the single statement inside the loop */
```

becomes:

```
; /* empty initial statement */
while (j) /* loop condition */
{
    /* the single statement inside the loop */

    printf("%d%d\t", i, j)); /* loop statement */
}
```

Please note that the loop statement is the **last** statement inside the controlled block.

The loop condition is just an expression. Any expression that evaluates to zero will be taken as `false`, any non-zero value will be `true`. So the condition can be written as:

```
while (j != 0) /* loop condition */
```

The statement inside the loop is

```
j = i++ <= 5;
```

As the post-increment will return the former value of `i`, it can be moved in a second statement:

```
j = i <= 5;
i++;
```

The assignment to `j` just evaluates the comparison `i <= 5` and stores its result in `j`, giving 0 when `false` (i > 5) and `true` (i <= 5), respectively.

The resulting source looks like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;

    while (j != 0)
    {
        j = i <= 5;
        i++;
        printf("%d%d\t", i, j);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now you should be able to understand what this code does.

You might like to be tempted to expand

```
j = i <= 5;
```

into

```
if (i <= 5)
{
    j = 1;
}
else
{
    j = 0;
}
```

But I think this just bloats the source. In modern C I would use `bool` as the type for `j` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go over how a `for` loop works in C:

```
for ( expr1opt ; expr2opt ; expr3opt )
  statement
```

`expr1`, if present, is evaluated first.  *Usually* this expression is meant to perform some kind of initialization on our loop counter or condition, but it doesn't have to.  In the case of this loop it's omitted since `i` and `j` have already been initialized.

After `expr1` has been evaluated and *before* each loop iteration, `expr2` is evaluated.  If the result is non-zero, the loop body is executed; otherwise the loop exits at that point.  In this case, `j` is evaluated.  As long as `j` doesn't equal zero, the loop body is executed.

The loop body compares the result of `i++` to `5`, and assigns the result of that comparison to `j`.  If `i` starts at `1`, then each iteration of the loop produces the following results:

```
j = 1 <= 5 == 1, i = i + 1 == 2;
j = 2 <= 5 == 1, i = i + 1 == 3;
j = 3 <= 5 == 1, i = i + 1 == 4;
j = 4 <= 5 == 1, i = i + 1 == 5;
j = 5 <= 5 == 1, i = i + 1 == 6;
j = 6 <= 5 == 0, i = i + 1 == 7;
```

Remember that the *result* of `i++` is the current value of `i` and the *side effect* is to add `1` to `i`.  Thus, if `i == 1`, then the *result* of `i++` is `1`.

*After* each loop iteration, `expr3` is evaluated.  *Usually* this expression updates our loop counter or condition, but again, it doesn't *have* to.  In this particular case, it prints out the values of `i` and `j`, so the output should be

```
21    31    41    51    61    70
```

A less confusing way of writing this loop would be

```
while ( j )
{
  j = i++ <= 5;
  printf( "%d%d\t", i, j );
}
```

The statement `j = i++ <= 5` is a shorthand way of writing

```
if ( i++ <= 5 )
  j = 1;
else
  j = 0;
```

The result of a comparison or equality operator is either a `0` or `1`, and you can assign the result of the comparison directly to another variable.